# Is there a way to visualize data in a Snowflake Python worksheet within a Snowpark session?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, visualization

New to Snowpark and am trying to analyze data from a table within Snowflake.  I am able to read the table and view Python output like describing the dataset and output dataframes but it doesn`t seem like Snowpark allows data visualization capabilities.  Can anyone share on this please?

Tried different libraries like matplotlib, streamlit but no output

Comment: Have you taken a look at Streamlit in Snowflake?
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-streamlit

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MikeWalton.  I tried a simple bar chart with Streamlit but got the output:

2023-08-25 13:10:37.237 

  [33m[1mWarning:[0m to view this Streamlit app on a browser, run it with the following command:

    streamlit run  [ARGUMENTS]

Comment: I'd open a support ticket with Snowflake to work through that issue with them.